# Gradle - dependencies with because statement

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I'm new to gradle, I found in build.gradle.kts inside dependencies [because clauses/statements](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/b15c922eee225567a7ed7442ff8c6c848de421cc/src/components/build.gradle.kts)

> ```
> dependencies { 
>   implementation("commons-io:commons-io") {
>       because("IOUtils")
>   }
>   implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text") {
>       because("StringEscapeUtils")
>   }
> ```

I didn't find in any [Gradle dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) such because clause

Is it just a custom clause similar to adding java docs and could have been rename to any string as `myreason("""my reason is other""")`

Or is `becasue` statement used by Gradle ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it in the `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency` internface

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Dependency.html#because-java.lang.String-

```
@Incubating
@Nullable
String getReason()

Returns a reason why this dependency should be used, in particular with regards to its version. The dependency report will use it to explain why a specific dependency was selected, or why a specific dependency version was used.

Returns:
   a reason to use this dependency
Since:
   4.6


@Incubating
void because​(@Nullable
             String reason)

Sets the reason why this dependency should be used.

Since:
    4.6
```

Comment: Thanks, why setter is `because` and getter is `getReason()`? I would expect to have `setReason` or `reason`

Comment: because: `getBecause()` would sound silly. It's a DSL for humans. My guess is that they tried to create an expressive API. Why they didn't name the method `reason(String)` I have no clue.